# Smooth fade in text animation doesnt work - React Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to achieve a smooth fade in text animation with CSS in React and Typescript using inline styling.I am creating an object with styling information, and refer to it in the style attribute. The code is down below. It does not work and I have a problem to get it work, can someone help or give some hints please?

Thats a working example what I am trying to achieve: https://codepen.io/kazed972/pen/bQOQGR

My code:

````
import React from 'react';

const styles = {
    body: {
        margin: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#232323',
        color: '#fff',
        fontFamily: 'Calibri, sans-serif',
        boxSizing: 'border-box',
    },

    center: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100vh',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },

    p: {
        width: '70%',
        fontSize: '30px',
        display: 'block',
        textAlign: 'center',
    },

    char: {
        fontSize: '40px',
        height: '40px',
        animation: 'an 1s ease-out 1 both',
        display: 'inline-block',
    },

    '@keyframes an': {
        from: {
            opacity: 0,
            transform: 'perspective(500px) translate3d(-35px, -40px, -150px) rotate3d(1, -1, 0, 35deg)',
        },
        to: {
            opacity: 1,
            transform: 'perspective(500px) translate3d(0, 0, 0)',
        },
    },
};

function FadeInText() {
    var text = document.getElementById('text') as HTMLElement;
    var newDom = '';
    var animationDelay = 6;

    for (let i = 0; i < text.innerText.length; i++) {
        newDom += '<span class="char">' + (text.innerText[i] === ' ' ? '&nbsp;' : text.innerText[i]) + '</span>';
    }

    text.innerHTML = newDom;
    var length = text.children.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        text.children[i].style['animation-delay'] = animationDelay * i + 'ms';
    }

    return (
        <div style={styles.center}>
            <p id="text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate incidunt praesentium, rerum
                voluptatem in reiciendis officia harum repudiandae tempore suscipit ex ea, adipisci ab porro.
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}

export { FadeInText };```
````

Comment: Ehm, it looks like you are mixing manual DOM manipulation with React. That usually isn't a good idea. You shouldn't use `getElementById`, `innerHTML` and such. Instead use React's DOM manipulation methods!

Comment: So you mean this should all happen in then return (... )?

Comment: React is based on state mutations implemented with hooks or class components. Basically if you don’t have useState your graph is reinitialised on each re render (and rerender happens on whatever prop is changed)

Comment: Check this guy out https://react-spring.dev/hooks/use-trail#usetrail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the solution with `styled-components` to keep your react component consistent.

I refactored the styles a bit. Now, parent element (Section) uses flexbox. (TextStyle) each letter has a default position with a transform that we can remove now from the keyframes and keep only the last frame. Also, (TextStyle) gets two props: delay and color as custom values.

##### TextAnimation.tsx

```js
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';

const an = keyframes`
  100% { opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) }
`;

const Section = styled.section`
  width: 70vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
`;

const TextStyle = styled.span<{ color: string; delay: number }>`
  animation: ${an} 1s ease-out forwards;
  animation-delay: ${(props) => props.delay}ms;
  color: ${(props) => props.color};
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.3;
  opacity: 0;
  transform-style: perspective(500px);
  transform: translate3d(-35px, -40px, -150px) rotate3d(1, -1, 0, 35deg);
`;

const DELAY = 6; // ms
export const TextAnimation = ({ text }: { text: string }) => {
  // Splitting text on each character and return an array of HTML nodes.
  const letters = text.split('').map((letter, index) => {
    // Calculate delay for each sign
    const delayCounter = DELAY * (index + 1);

    return (
      <TextStyle key={index} delay={delayCounter} color="white">
        {letter === ' ' ? <>&nbsp;</> : letter}
      </TextStyle>
    );
  });

  return <Section>{letters}</Section>;
};
```

##### App.tsx

```js
import { TextAnimation } from "./TextAnimation";

export default function App() {
  const text =
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate incidunt praesentium, rerum voluptatem in reiciendis officia harum repudiandae tempore suscipit ex ea, adipisci ab porro.";
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextAnimation text={text} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a React way of achieving the effect you are after:

**FadeInText.js:**

```
const FadeInText = ({ text }) => {
  return (
    <div className="center">
      <p>{addAnimation(text)}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const addAnimation = (text) => {
  const ANIMATION_DELAY = 6;

  // The below turns a string into an array of characters and replaces empty spaces with &nbsp; (i.e. 'a b' --> ['a', <>&nbsp;</>, 'b'])
  const allChars = [...text].map((char) => (char === " " ? <>&nbsp;</> : char));

  return allChars.map((char, i) => {
    return (
      <span
        key={i}
        className="char"
        style={{ animationDelay: `${ANIMATION_DELAY * i}ms` }}
      >
        {char}
      </span>
    );
  });
};

export default FadeInText;
```

This is how to use the above component:

**App.js:**

```
import FadeInText from "./FadeInText";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FadeInText text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate incidunt praesentium, rerum voluptatem in reiciendis officia harum repudiandae tempore suscipit ex ea, adipisci ab porro." />
      <FadeInText text="Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world!" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**styles.css:**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #232323;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}

.center {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

p {
  width: 70%;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.char {
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  animation: an 1s ease-out 1 both;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes an {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: perspective(500px) translate3d(-35px, -40px, -150px)
      rotate3d(1, -1, 0, 35deg);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: perspective(500px) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

View it in action here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-jepsen-bivcku?file=/src/FadeInText.js

Comment: And if I do not use a css file but do it in a const styles = {...}, how would I apply the char or keyframes in the css inline? Do you know that?

Comment: I don't think adding keyframes as an inline style can be done as they need to be declared at a global level. Adding a `<style>` block inside the component like this works: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-hypatia-0j07dg , but will result in multiple `<style>` blocks for every time that component is used on a page. A better approach might be to consider using the keyframes helper in [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#animations) or [Emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/keyframes) as these libraries will handle things like name collisions.